# Multidimensional scaling in R (done manually)

Tags: multi-dimensional-scaling

How to do multidimensional scaling by iterative majorization in R manually? Does anyone have an idea how to code Guttman`s transform?

Answer (score 0):

Try smacof, an R package.  Be sure to examine the sample data structure str(bread) and figure out how to build it.  Guttman's Transform and its matrix algebra is presented in Modern Multidimensional Scaling by Ingwer Borg and Patrick J.F. Groenen, Spring 2005, which was named that by some of the developers of smacof according to Borg and Groenen and also discussed in conjunction with the package (see its Vignette).